# Which dialects conjugate "nosotros" differently in the indicative present and preterite (-ar verbs)?

Tags: verbos, diferencias-regionales, españa, conjugación, dialectos

In standard Spanish, the indicative present and preterite are conjugated identically for *nosotros* in *-ar* (and -ir) verbs:

- *Hablamos* - We speak
- *Hablamos* - We spoke

However in many closely related languages [there is a distinction](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/28224/18348):

- amamos (present) / amámos (preterite) `Portuguese (Eur)`
- amamos (present) / amemos (preterite) `Asturian/Mirandese`
- amamos (present) / amimos (preterite) `Ladino`

And apparently a similar distinction is made in some Spanish dialects:

> Some features exhibited in the women's prayer book are purely morphological, such as the use of the variant *-emos* (...), corresponding to Standard Castillian *-amos* **(although *-emos* is known in popular and regional Spanish) as the first person plural preterite marker of *-ar* conjugation verbs.**
>
> - [*Distinctive Characteristics of Jewish Ibero-Romance, circa 1492*](http://www.academia.edu/1140051/Distinctive_Characteristics_of_Jewish_Ibero-Romance_circa_1492), (p.109-110)

Which dialects are these?

Comment: Related: [¿Por qué se usa el subjuntivo para indicar pasado?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/28602/1674)

Comment: Aunque esta información es interesante no se si esto es off-topic. Una cosa es hablar de diferencias regionales en el uso del español y ya otra hablar de dialectos relacionados. ¿O seria válido hacer preguntas sobre catalán o aragonés aquí? No lo creo. Eso sería tan valido como preguntar sobre griego o latín.

Comment: @DGaleano quería preguntar sobre dialectos *de* castellano, a los que refiere la cita: "although *-emos* is known in popular and regional Spanish"

Comment: DGaleano no creo que esté preguntando sobre el asturiano, ladino, etc, sino dando información de fondo (que recalca que su existencia en castellano será más histórico que erróneo).  Sabemos por la pregunta de fedorqui que existe en lengua castellana, y ahora se pregunta dónde se emplea (que, como vemos, coinciden en gran parte con estas lenguas).  No creo que una pregunta sobre alguna forma hipotética argentina que parezca, digamos, una forma italiana sea off-topic, siempre que la pregunta se dirige a la existencia/historia/origen de la forma en castellano.

Comment: Uf. Tantos errores de tecleo en mi comentario.

Comment: @guifa el título es "Which dialects conjugate...". Creo entonces que debería cambiarse. Así como esta pregunta sobre dialectos y no sobre español. O no se si no estoy entendiendo pero para mi "el argentino", "el colombiano" etc no son dialectos. Yo considero que hablo español así sea muy diferente del que se habla en Cuba o España.

Comment: @DGaleano I'm using dialect here in its [usual meaning](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/dialect) of "a particular form of a language which is peculiar to a specific region or social group etc". There is a secondary meaning (sometimes used pejoratively), of regional languages which do not have the same social/political status as the prestige dialect/language (e.g. Occitan vs Parisian French, Galician vs Castilian Spanish), but this isn't the usage I meant.

Comment: @DGaleano p. ej., hay una gran diferencia entre el *dialecto* asturiano (del castellano), en el cual es común escuchar algo como *díjele* (en vez de *le he dicho*, más frecuente en España), y la *lengua* asturiana (proveniente del antiguo leonés) en el cual la misma frase sería *díxi-y*. Hay razones, muchas nacionalistas, de un siglo ha por que en mucha de la literatura lingüística de España se confunden —incluso a propósito— el dialecto asturiano/aragonés/catalán del castellano con los idiomas correspondientes a esas regiones.  Más difícil es confundir el dialecto vasco con el euskera jaja.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to have been a general phenomenon in Old Spanish, but is now limited to disparate dialects across Spain (mostly coinciding with regional languages which have this distinction). The paper quoted lists further resources in a footnote:

> <sup>**18.** On *-emos* and *-stes* in Spanish, see:</sup>
>   <sup>• Zamora Vicente, [*Dialectología Española*](https://books.google.co.uk/books?redir_esc=y&id=7tCwAAAAIAAJ&focus=searchwithinvolume&q=emos), p.184;</sup>
>   <sup>• García de Diego, [*Gramática histórica española*](https://archive.org/details/elementosdegram00garcuoft/page/142), p.229;</sup>
>   <sup>• Lapresa, *Historia*, pp. 302-303;</sup>
>   <sup>• M. Alvar and B. Pottier, [*Morfología histórica del español*](https://books.google.co.uk/books?redir_esc=y&id=SGAkAAAAMAAJ), p.273;</sup>
>   <sup>• Penny, [*A History of the Spanish Language*](https://books.google.co.uk/books?redir_esc=y&id=ZjcrhyQlFa0C), pp. 179-189</sup>

A number of these make note that these developments emerged Old Spanish, and were used frequently in Medieval literature, but since have been restricted to 'rural' varieties:

> The medieval forms *cantest(e), cantemos, cantestes* borrowed their tonic vowel from first-person-singular *canté* as a result of an analogical imitation of the *-ir* preterite, where the same tonic vowel occurred in all the corresponding forms. Thus, *oí : oíste :: canté : x* (*x = canteste*), etc.
> These forms with /é/, although frequent in Old Spanish, were later restricted to
> rural varieties of the language.
>
> - [*A History of the Spanish Language*](https://books.google.co.uk/books?redir_esc=y&id=ZjcrhyQlFa0C&q=179&q=cantemos) (3.7.8.6.1.1, p.218)

> *Pretérito perfecto*... en el siglo XIII la forma común de la segunda persona era en *-este*... con *e* analógica de la primera persona, y acaso de la segunda de plural de las otras conjucaciones, *valiestes, saliestes*; pero *-aste*, sea que se hubiese conservado oscurecida, sea un innovación según *amamos, amastes, amaron*, con fortuita coincidencia con su etimología, es lo cierto que prevaleció pronto y acabó por anular a *-este:* **la primera persona de plural es *-emos* entre el vulgo, *amemos, llevemos,* con *e* analógica de *amé*, influyendo acaso en esta innovación la tendencia a deferenciarle del presente.**
>
> - [*Gramática histórica española*](https://archive.org/details/elementosdegram00garcuoft/page/142) (p.143)

> Las medievales *cantest(e), cantemos, cantestes*, toman la vocal tónica por analogía con la 1ª sing. *canté*.
>
> - [*Morfología histórica del español*](https://books.google.co.uk/books?redir_esc=y&id=SGAkAAAAMAAJ)

The following note specific areas where said conjugations still exist dialectally:

> En las hablas aragonesas, *trajes* (cheso) es analógica de Yo *traje* + *-s*, *trajemos* de los verbos en *-ar* (*cantemos* etc.);
>
> - Ibid.

> Hoy, la forma *-emos* se usa en tierra leonesa y estremeña (y en Castilla como vulgarismo) y ambas personas (*cantemos, cantesteis*) se usan algo en Asturias y en Miranda.
>
> - [*Dialectología Española*](https://books.google.co.uk/books?redir_esc=y&id=7tCwAAAAIAAJ&focus=searchwithinvolume&q=emos), p.184

Comment: Es decir, básicamente donde hay otras lenguas que emplean *-emos*, puede ocurrir.  El aragonés tiene *-emos* (en la forma sintética), y aunque no tengo tanta experiencia con él, me imagino que el estremeño — dialecto del leonés — lo tendrá tiene.   A veces algunos libros tratan al aragonés y asturiano como dialectos del castellano (y el mirandés como del portugués), por lo que no sé hasta qué punto son propiamente características del castellano dialectal o meramente influencia (o descripción directa) de otras lenguas.  (Tendría que leer D.E. con más detalle)