# ¿Por qué se usa el subjuntivo para indicar pasado?

Tags: verbos, españa, subjuntivo, conjugación, pretérito

Leo con frecuencia en ambientes coloquiales (grupos de WhatsApp, o redes sociales, por ejemplo) de España frases del tipo:

> —Ayer <s>**hablemos**</s> con Juan.
>
> —El otro día <s>**cenemos**</s> en un restaurante kurdo.

En lugar del correcto:

> —Ayer **hablamos** con Juan.
>
> —El otro día **cenamos** en un restaurante kurdo.

Es decir, se usa el presente del subjuntivo en lugar del pretérito del indicativo.

Pensando en cuándo y cómo he oído esto, me doy cuenta que suele ser siempre en verbos terminados en *-ar*.

En general lo leo y oigo en gente con no demasiada educación, pero me resulta chocante. ¿Hay algún momento en el que haya sido de uso común? ¿Existe alguna explicacion *histórica* de su uso ciertamente extendido?

Comment: ¿Podrías especificar dónde o en qué contexto has escuchado esas frases?

Comment: Sí, de hecho tanto en asturiano como en aragonés y mirandés es exactamente esa conjugación.  En portugués, hay una diferencia menor, que va de *falamos/cenamos* (-â-) a *falámos/cenámos*).  En el castellano antiguamente se usaba a veces

Comment: No obstante, para la mayoría de los hablantes que lo emplean, probablemente es por analogía con la primera persona singular más que por historia y así sería más del tipo *-astes* en el pretérito indefinido tuteante.

Comment: @prm296 como comentaba en la pregunta, es en ambiente bastante coloquial. En particular, últimamente lo he visto en conversaciones de grupos de WhatsApp de España Actualizo la pregunta con estos datos.

Comment: ¿y podrías decir de dónde son esas personas de los grupos de Whatsapp? Porque yo nunca lo he oído, salvo quizás en alguna parodia muy forzada, ^^

Comment: @FGSUZ España en general. El caso particular que me viene a la cabeza es gente nacida en Cataluña castellanoparlante con raíces en otras parte de España.

Comment: Ah y claro también en catalán es lo mismo, aunque por mi entender lo normal es emplear, un poco como en ciertos dialectos del aragonés, una forma perifrástica con *va- + [inf]* para representar el pretérito indefinido, ¿no?  Es decir, mejor pregunta: ¿por qué en castellano es *-amos*?  jaja

Comment: @guifa sí, la forma _va + [inf]_ es la que se usa siempre en catalán. Técnicamente se podría decir _pujàrem_ ("subimos") pero siempre se dice _vàrem pujar_ / _vam pujar_.

Comment: @guifa hay una propuesta de sitio Stack sobre el Catalán por cierto, guiño guiño : ) https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/121280/catalan-language

Comment: yo he oído también lo que comenta fedorqui, siempre en la  primera persona del plural cuando el preterito perfecto simple coincide con el presente. Sobre todo lo he oído a gitanos pero también a payos aunque menos.

Comment: @ukemi good one! Your answer there does not mention Catalan areas (you say you have a limited access to that resource). Do you think it is possible to get the full content and confirm this is the case?

Comment: @fedorqui when I wrote the question I was hoping someone with more expertise on the topic would answer with their own easier-to-access sources haha I'll have another look and update if I do. Will un-accept my own answer if someone else replies with a more comprehensive one.